# Operand data type varchar is invalid for multiply operator in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, varchar

I'm writing a simple query and have the error saying
"Operand data type varchar is invalid for multiply operator"

Here is a query:

```
declare @Num  varchar(24)   
set @Num = '11112222333334444'

select SUBSTRING(@Num, 1, 6) + ISNULL(REPLICATE(''*'', LEN(@Num) - 7), '''') + RIGHT(@Num, 1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I have extra `'` in my code